# Java http request to local apache server - UnknownHostException

Tags: java, apache, http, request, local

I am running a apache local server with xampp on my windows.
I am trying to test my php backend with some Http requests.

I am getting an java.net.UnknownHostException when I am trying to connect with my Java program. 
I could swap and download a chrome extension for making the requests, but I want access my server later on with an android app, written in java, so I need working code.

The server is running and I can access it with chrome.

This is my java code (without import and package):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RemoteConnecter connector = new RemoteConnecter("", "");

        ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
        params.add("intent=connect");

        System.out.println(connector.request(params));
    }

  }


  public class RemoteConnecter {

    String password;
    String username;

    public RemoteConnecter(String username, String password) {
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String request(ArrayList<String> params) {

        String temp = null;

        String urllink = "https://www.Jobads43.wpm";
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urllink);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            //params
            String urlParams = "user=" + username + "&password=" + password;
            for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
                urlParams += "&" + params.get(i);
            }

            byte[] postData       = urlParams.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
            int    postDataLength = postData.length;
            con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
            con.setUseCaches( false );
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( con.getOutputStream()/*Exception is thrown here*/);
            output.write( postData );

            BufferedReader in = null;
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line;


            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            in.close();
            temp = sb.toString();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

This is the excerp of my vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\path-is-correct-but-not-shown"
    ServerName Jobads43.wpm
    ServerAlias www.JobAds.local
    <Directory />
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "C:\xampp\htdocs\log"
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is in my hosts

```
127.0.0.1           Jobads43.wpm
```

I am sorry for the formatting, i can't do it better ...
In the edit it is formatted better

Can you help me?

UPDATE:
when I use the url "https://Jobads43.wpm" I get a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
when I use the url "http://Jobads43.wpm" its working.
But I need to use https protocol to securely send my data. how to do ?

Comment: Try setting the `urllink` to 'https://jobads43.wpm`

Comment: @KevinO I have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stel 1:Create certificate using java keytool.
Step2: configure apache to access https instead of http. To do this follow the below link,

https://gist.github.com/nguyenanhtu/33aa7ffb6c36fdc110ea8624eeb51e69

Step 3: import the same cerificate (which you created at step 1) in java cert file which will be inside the security folder in java.

This will resolve handshake issue

Comment: hows the file called?

Comment: Please mention the file name which you commented

Comment: the java cert file: I have a cacerts file and a blacklist.certs file

Comment: You want me to tell how to create the certificate or how to import the certificate in java

Comment: how to import the cert

Comment: Let me give you the import cmd

Comment: Use this cmd, keytool -import -file E:\yourcertificate.crt -keypass changeit -keystore "C:\... \jre\lib\security\cacerts"

Comment: Note: Use quotation symbol if you have space inbetween the location directory names how i used in java location